# Como reproduzir áudio de um captcha em PHP?

Tags: php, áudio, captcha

Olá. Desenvolvi um simples CAPTCHA em PHP e agora estou tentando fazer um script que gere um áudio a partir do código gerado. Tenho um áudio mp3 para cada letra e número, e minha solução momentânea é a seguinte:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $vetorLetras = str_split($_SESSION['captcha']); //esse é o código gerado pelo CAPTCHA
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    foreach ($vetorLetras as $letra) {
        echo file_get_contents('audios/'.$letra.'.mp3');
    }
?>
```

E esse código funciona perfeitamente! O resultado é exatamente o esperado, basta chamar esse arquivo como um áudio pela tag <audio>. Mas pelo que eu pesquisei, é incorreto realizar isso dessa maneira, dando 'echo' no conteúdo de áudios dessa forma. Busco agora uma solução correta. Acredito que em PHP puro não seja possível unir áudios de forma simples. Estava pensando em um script que roda no lado do cliente que execute os áudios do código um de cada vez em sequência, mas não sei como fazer isso de forma segura, sem mostrar o valor do CAPTCHA no código fonte, mas não descarto também a possibilidade de fazer o áudio pelo PHP, talvez em outro formato como WAV seja possível. Alguém sabe como fazer?